# MobileConnect Re-optin methods

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobileconnect, sms

I have a contact who was opted into KEYWORD1 and has opted out of SMS by texting "STOP". Next to the keyword, under subscriptions, it says Not Opted In.
This person was then added to KEYWORD2 via import definition and next to keyword 2 under subscriptions, it says Opted In and he started receiving SMS again from us. Is this the expected behaviouir?

I'd like to confirm that re-importing contacts via the import defitinion re-opts in contacts in MobileConnect after they have opted out by texting STOP keyword?

In addition, is there any other ways re-optin can happen?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, re-importing the contacts manually opts in the contacts to the **specific keyword** you select in the import wizard.

There are two other ways of re-opt in contacts to a keyword.

1. Contact API. Refer the answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/331113/mobile-opt-in-bulk/331125#331125)
2. [Queue MO API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postQueueMO.htm)

In both cases, you need a create an [optin in response message](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_moc_mobile_opt-in.htm&type=5) and activate it. Be mindful, that if you use the Queue MO API, the user is sent the optin message confirming the subscription.

Answer (score 0):

The global stop keywords like STOP opts out of all keywords from that Long/short code at that point.

In your case, since the opt-in to a keyword (KEYWORD2) happened later on, it is the expected behaviour.

Apart from both the methods mentioned in previous answer to re-opt in, sending a message via API is another way by keeping resubscribe = true. More details at https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381673&type=1